# eth0 r8169 down on wake up from standby

Tags: debian, networking, acpi, ethernet, networkmanager

On waking up after standby the network (eth0) remains down. The eth0 card is r8169.

I have tried :

- `ifconfig eth0 up`
  Doesn't work
- `ifconfig eth0 up; dhcpcd eht0`
  Worked but how do I configure my static ip with this, my proxy is ip bound

### This works:

> this commands gets the network up with the conventional network manager:
> `modprobe -r r8169; modprobe r8169; service network-manager restart`

**But is there any way to automate this or modify the acpi scripts so that no modprobe is required in the first place?**

### Config details:

OS: Debian-squeeze (6.0)

`ethtool eth0` output:

```
Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                        100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
Advertised pause frame use: No
Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                     100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
Link partner advertised pause frame use: No
Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
Speed: 100Mb/s
Duplex: Full
Port: MII
PHYAD: 0
Transceiver: internal
Auto-negotiation: on
Supports Wake-on: pumbg
Wake-on: g
Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
Link detected: yes
```

File `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug eth0
#NetworkManager#iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Comment: Have you tried bringing the interface up and running the DHCP client manually?

Comment: @phun I have already set up my dhcp to manual

Comment: Please edit the question to make your it clearer. What's the outcome that you would expect? Are you able to get the connection up and running after the sleep using, say, `ifconfig eth0 up` and `dhcpcd eth0`?

Comment: @phune `ifconfig eth0 up; dhcpcd eht0` worked but how can I configure it for my static ip. Also the network manager applet doesn't works either with this, i guess because now connection is being managed by other app?

Answer (score 1):

That you have to remove and restore the device's module is an indication that it doesn't handle sleep/wakeup well. Check if there is a newer kernel available for your distribution, or compile your own.

Answer (score 0):

It's a common IRQ problem with Realtek cards. Look at your logs. You will see something like:

```
Jul 10 08:47:34 xxx systemd-logind[861]: Operation 'sleep' finished.
Jul 10 08:47:34 xxx NetworkManager[845]: <info>  [1531205254.1392] manager: sleep: wake requested (sleeping: yes  enabled: yes)
Jul 10 08:47:34 xxx NetworkManager[845]: <info>  [1531205254.1394] device (enp24s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 10 08:47:34 xxx kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp24s0: link is not ready
Jul 10 08:47:34 xxx gnome-shell[3792]: _st_paint_shadow_with_opacity: assertion 'shadow_pipeline != NULL' failed
Jul 10 08:47:34 xxx NetworkManager[845]: <info>  [1531205254.1965] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Jul 10 08:47:34 xxx kernel: do_IRQ: 13.36 No irq handler for vector
Jul 10 08:47:34 xxx kernel: r8169 0000:18:00.0 enp24s0: link down
```